# asp.net application start and end event sequence

Tags: asp.net, events

We are logging both events, however Instead of seeing them in pair we see Application start more. what i mean is instead of

Application start, end, start, end, start, end ...

we see

Application start, end, start, start, end ... (see two starts without end)

is it normal? Does application restarts without Application_End event not fired?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason for such behavior is w3wp crash. Look for W3WP crash events in Windows Event Log.

Comment: I checked the event viewer and could not find any entries that could explain what you mentioned. Anything you can point to...